# Unable to split date and from from datetime

Tags: php, codeigniter

Fatal error: Call to a member function format() on a non-object in

View

```
 <?php

        $date = $listProject->enddate;
   $data['enddate'] = $date->format('Y-m-d');
   $time['time'] = $date->format('H:i:s');

                                              ?>

 <?php echo get_datetime($listProject->enddate);?>(<?php echo '<b style="color:red;">'.days_left($listProject->enddate,$listProject->id).'</b>';?>)
```

Controller

```
$this->outputData['listProjects']   = $this->skills_model->getProjects($urgent_conditions,NULL,NULL,array(15),$order);
$this->load->view('listProjects',$this->outputData);
```

Model

```
$this->db->select('projects.created,projects.enddate');
```

Thank you! :D
I tried to do it on VIew and controller but still getting error, the error above is caused by View

Add on Found this in MY_date_helper

```
if ( ! function_exists('get_datetime'))
```

{
    function get_datetime($timestamp)

```
{
    $CI =& get_instance();
    $CI->lang->load('enduser/common');
    if(date('d/M/Y') == date('d/M/Y',$timestamp))
    $date = $CI->lang->line('Today at')." ".date('H:i',$timestamp)." UTC";
    else
    $date = date('d-M-Y H:i',$timestamp)." UTC";        
    return $date;
}
```

PHP Version :  5.2.17

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$date = new DateTime($listProject->enddate);
```

instead of

```
$date = $listProject->enddate;
```

Edit: Make that:

```
$date = new DateTime();
$date->setTimestamp($listProject->enddate);
```

Comment: A PHP ERROR WAS ENCOUNTERED

Severity: Warning

Message: DateTime::__construct() [datetime.--construct]: Failed to parse time string (1351353236) at position 7 (2): Unexpected character

Filename: views/listProjects.php

Comment: The datetime is in this format 27-Oct-2012 10:53 UTC , not sure where the UTC came from hmm

Comment: I just realise 1351191137 < is the end date isit like encoded or something?

Comment: Call to undefined method DateTime::setTimestamp() in

Comment: Ummm... http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimestamp.php Hmm are you running <= 5.3?

Comment: 5.2.17 <--- PHP VERSION , i also added something above

Comment: Yes you won't be able to use the DateTime object. I don't think you actually need these two lines: $data['enddate'] = $date->format('Y-m-d'); $time['time'] = $date->format('H:i:s'); and it's those that are causing the error.

Comment: But without those or something else i wont be able to split Date and time. :O I need those 2 split up :(

Comment: 1351353236 << seems like my datetime is in this format, is that normal? :O I tried this $tijd[] = $listProject->enddate;

$date = new DateTime($tijd[0]);

echo $date->format('U');

Comment: That is a unix timestamp. Look at my previous comment for how to use it to get a true date format.

Comment: date('d/m/Y', $listProject->enddate) < Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

use `strtotime`...

```
 <?php

$date = $listProject->enddate;
$data['enddate']=date('Y-m-d',strtotime($date));
$time['time'] = date('H:i:s',strtotime($date));
```

Comment: $time['time'] = date('H:i:s',strtotime($date)); returns the word ARRAY
$data['enddate']=date('d',strtotime($date)); returns 1351353236

Comment: The datetime is in this format 27-Oct-2012 10:53 UTC , not sure where the UTC came from hmm

Answer (score 1):

I recently had the same problem in my CI project. I solved it with this method, it works:

Even this string below gave same error:

```
$date = new DateTime($listProject->enddate);
```

I solved it with this:

```
$date = new DateTime(strtotime($listProject->enddate));
```

and then below it, format the time as you please:

```
$date->format('d/m/Y');
```

The main reason here is, some how your date string contains some characters which DateTime method don't know! strtotime() method correctly converts your string to the date format.

Comment: asked 3 years ago HAHAHA. Nevertheless thanks for the contribution :)